# Why does it give me a "Failed to resolve" error in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to learn Android and I tried to make an example from a tutorial. I have to include two libraries in the build.gradle, but when I sync the project with the gradle files it gives me this error: "Failed to resolve".

Here is the dependecies part from build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1'
```

}

Is there somethig wrong with the versions of the libraries or is it something else?

Comment: Can you post the log which line shows the error! Because some of the given library is not downloaded or not available to access!

Comment: Post your full build.gradle

Comment: You probably haven't downloaded the the Support Repository and Support libraries in the SDK Manager.

Comment: @KevinChris I am pretty new to Android but I guess this is what are you asking for `Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.1.1
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>` and the other one `Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>`

Comment: post the entire build.gradle file.

Answer (score 3):

In your `build.gradle` you have to add:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Gradle has to know where to download the aar files.

Pay attention to your example. You are using picasso:2.1.1.
It is a very old version.
[Here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.squareup.picasso%22%20AND%20a%3A%22picasso%22) you can find all releases of this library.

Comment: I checked and it's there

Comment: @Pikachuu Yes, it is there, I am only saying that it is an old version.

Comment: Try to use the latest version of both the libraries @Pikachuu.

Answer (score 0):

So it unable to resolve the jar! So I believe you missing `jcenter()` in your `build.gradle`. Your build.gradle should look like this

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

And your'e using older version of `picasso` library, the new version is `2.5.2`

Still if face the problem you can download the `JAR` and add to `libs` folder.

You can find jar from this [link](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Answer (score 0):

1.download the jar file of picasso from  this site square.github.io/picasso/
2.add the jar file to your app/lib folder
3.from android studio go to file/project structure/dependency then click on the blue + button then jar dependency from the lib folder select picasso at last press ok

Answer (score 0):

in my case adding mavencentral to gradle worked
I took it from here

[Could not find com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379226/could-not-find-com-squareup-picassopicasso2-5-2/37379356#37379356)

```
enter repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```