# Could not find com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, build.gradle

I adding picasso dependencies but seem it not worked. I tried changing the version. But still useless.

This my build.gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bhouse.travellist_starterproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.1'

}
```

and this is my build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

The error said:

> Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.1
>   Show in File
> Show in
>   Project Structure dialog

Any help are welcome.

Comment: Try removing the semi colon after jcenter()

Comment: @DanielK , still won't solve the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a section `allprojects` at the end of your main `build.gradle` that defines the repositories for the modules of your project:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

This will result in the following `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to their [Github](https://github.com/square/picasso), you have to use MavenCentral to get their library so add this to your build.gradle(app) file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Resync and try again.

Comment: `jcenter()` works as well, because it is a superset of Maven Central

Comment: @MarcinKoziński, ah did not realize that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a maven repository from which Picasso can be downloaded. You can do that by adding this in your app module's `build.gradle` file:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

A good place would be just before your `dependencies {}` block.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I just set in the `gradle.properties` settings for https

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=some.proxy.adress.com

systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

so in my case, `gradle.properties` will be:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Begins when I use the app,and just have a build (module) without build (app).

After I add Picasso library appears Error: (line, column) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.picasso: Picasso: 2.5.2 Show in File || Show in Project Structure dialog

as well as with the glide library

and the solution is as it says (DenisGL) is added allprojects follows:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter ()
    }
}
```