# Got Error during adding picasso dependencies com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, build.gradle

I trying to add picasso dependencies even any dependencies but got Error:

> Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2
>   Show in File Show in Project Structure dialog

whats the problem & any solution?

my build.gradle (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'  

android {  
compileSdkVersion 25  
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"  
defaultConfig {  
    applicationId "com.example.dr.myapplication"  
    minSdkVersion 18  
    targetSdkVersion 25  
    versionCode 1  
    versionName "1.0"  
    testInstrumentationRunner  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}  
buildTypes {  
    release {  
        minifyEnabled false  
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),  
  'proguard-rules.pro'  
        }  
    }  
}  

dependencies {  
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')  
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',   {  
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'  
})  

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'  
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'  
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

my build.gradle(project)

```
buildscript {    
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

  allprojects {
     repositories {
       jcenter()

   }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Pls post line from `gradle` file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37379226/could-not-find-com-squareup-picassopicasso2-5-2)

Comment: i already read that thread but not solved my problem.